# pyinstaller FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory with --onefile only

Tags: python, pyinstaller

My exe file unable to find the folder, though i have added in datas.

First i create .spec file

```
pyinstaller --onefile app.py --name myapp
```

Then i edit .spec file as follow

```
datas=[('models','models'),('nltkdata','nltkdata')],
```

Then I do

```
python -m PyInstaller myapp.spec
```

Now when i run exe, it throw this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models/logisticregression.pkl'
```

Here is directory structure
[image]

EDIT:
Its working if i call my app this way

```
dist/myapp
```

But its not working if i cd into dist
and then do

```
./myapp
```

EDIT2:
If I removed `--onefile`. its working. But i want one file

Comment: Make sure you're running the exe in dist and not build

Comment: yes, i am running the one in dist folder

Comment: create a [example] or a link to github repo

Answer (score 0):

On windows I have to provide my data to the .spec file like this:

```py
datas=[('./models','models'), ('./nltkdata','nltkdata')]
```

Comment: not working. i also assume that it should work, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Here it is

```
bundle_dir = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

os.path.abspath(os.path.join(bundle_dir, "models/logisticregression.pkl"))
```

source: [github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4946)